# ElasticSearch mapper to insert data in ES

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I was write the mapper for insert data into elastic index but I got following error.

elasticsearch.BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'not_x_content_exception: Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes')

```
mapper = {"mappings":
    {
        "event_info": {"type": "nested",
                       "properties": {
                           "type_info": {"type": "text"},
                           "op_type": {"type": "text"},
                           "file_name": {"type": "text"},
                           "file_ext": {"type": "text"},
                           "process_id": {"type": "text"},
                           "time_stamp": {"type": "text"}
                       }
                       }
    }
}
```

```
data = [{'event_info': [{'type_info': 'INFO', 'op_type': 'WRITE', 'file_name': '0.txt', 'file_ext': '.txt', 'process_id': '1234', 'time_stamp': '2022-10-17 05:23:06.8620427 +0000 UTC'}]}]
```

Need to create correct mapper for inserting data. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Elasticsearch 8.5.0, this works for me.

Mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "event_info": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "type_info": {"type": "text"},
                "op_type": {"type": "text"},
                "file_name": {"type": "text"},
                "file_ext": {"type": "text"},
                "process_id": {"type": "text"},
                "time_stamp": {"type": "text"}
            }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Document format to insert:

```
{
  "event_info" : {
      "type_info": "INFO", 
      "op_type": "WRITE", 
      "file_name": "0.txt", 
      "file_ext": ".txt", 
      "process_id": "1234", 
      "time_stamp": "2022-10-17 05:23:06.8620427 +0000 UTC"
   }
}
```

If using [bulk](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) you can put the document with:

```
{"index": {"_index": "your_index"}}
{"event_info": {"type_info": "INFO", "op_type": "WRITE", "file_name": "0.txt","file_ext": ".txt", "process_id": "1234", "time_stamp": "2022-10-17 05:23:06.8620427 +0000 UTC"}}
```

Comment: how can I write a search query on same data ex: I want to search "type_info"="INFO"

Comment: You can find everything explained in the documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "event_info",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "match": {
                            "event_info.type_info": "INFO"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}